# Swift 3: Getting data asynchronously before iPhone app launched

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my app I have to get some data from webmethod before app launched, so I have to  call a webmethod in this function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}
```

How can I block the function until the webmethod return its result?

Comment: You don't block that method, ever. If you do, iOS will kill your app for taking too long to launch.

Comment: So, what I have to do if I want the  "Launch screen" stay until the webmethod finish?

Comment: Implement a similar view to your launch screen and show it as soon as your app launches, so it looks like the launch screen and your custom view are the same.

Comment: Thank you @AndyIbanez
It was a useful suggestion